# Bootstrap navbar fixed on scroll

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I've been struggling on this issue for a while, so I thought I'd come to stackoverflow for help.
My code: http://pastebin.com/H4PHdguq

Bascially, what I want to accomplish is that when you scroll down, the navbar sticks to the top of the page. (Becomes fixed)
I've been unable to accomplish this through methods such as affix, probably because I've been doing it wrong(?)

Any help or input is appreciated!

Note: I've cut out the CSS styling because it isnt nesercarry towards the question. Also excuse the kinda messy code :).

**Code**

```
<header class="masthead">
  <div class="container" style="text-align:center;">
  <h2 class="enjoy-css" style="padding-top:10px    !important;">PIXELDESIGN</h2>
  <p style="color:white; font-family:Source Sans Pro; text-shadow: 2px 1px #222; font-size:18px">TEST</p>
```

```
<!-- Begin Navbar -->
<div id="nav">
  <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static">
 <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="/index.html">TEST</a></li>
             <li><a href="/portfolio.html">TEST</a></li>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="grow" style="background-color: #39D6A3 !important; box-shadow: inset 0px -3px 0px #32BF91;"><a href="/contact.php">  CONTACT ME    </a></li>


          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
  </div><!-- /.navbar -->
  </nav>
</div>

<style>
body {
  min-height:2000px;
 }
</style>`
```

Comment: Please include all relevant code in your post and **don't** just include a link to jsFiddle/pastebin. Your post should stand alone from any other resource;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try navbar-fixed-top rather than navbar-static.

Comment: See, I want to have the header "dissapear" when you scroll. Leaving only the navbar, so I don't think its this simple.

Comment: which header are you talking about? can you create a plunker or jsfiddle?

Comment: I see. are you using other frameworks? or just bootstrap?

Comment: Thanks, sdfarce! This works exactly as needed. The only problem I have it is that the transition between it being static and fixed is plain.. Is there any way I could add some sort of animation to the transition of the classes to make it more smooth?

Comment: I've found a better way to explain myself; When the bootstrap transitions to fixed top, the items in the menu seem to change position, how could I keep them the same to make it more smooth?

Comment: haven't you checked my last comment? that's a different fiddle.

Comment: For bootstrap 4 you have to use "fixed-top".

Answer (score 0):

Well, using navbar-fixed top instead of navbar-static will solve your problem. I have created a jsfiddle to show that and its that simple.

```
<div id="nav">
  <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
 <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="/index.html">TEST</a></li>
             <li><a href="/portfolio.html">TEST</a></li>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="grow" style="background-color: #39D6A3 !important; box-shadow: inset 0px -3px 0px #32BF91;"><a href="/contact.php">  CONTACT ME    </a></li>


          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
  </div><!-- /.navbar -->
  </nav>
</div>
```

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mayank_shubham/jzdhvfmv/